# how can I tell if the last x rows of 'state' = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a SQL query.

I have a table with a 'state' column.  0 means closed and 1 means opened.

Different users want to be notified after there have been x consecutive 1 events.

With an SQL query, how can I tell if the last x rows of 'state' = 1?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please define "consecutive" and "last"? SQL databases have no way to know which is "last" unless you have a column you can `ORDER BY`, but you've provided no information about your data other than one column. Is there a column that indicates a date or some other way to order the data to be able to tell what is "consecutive"? It helps if you provide enough information about your data to describe the condition(s) you're trying to match. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm rather new at this.
The table has:
ID unique,autonumber
Processor foreign key
Status_datetime timestamp
state 0 or 1

Let's say the Processor = 3.  I need to know when the last x records  where Processor = 3 have a state of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, you want to check if the last 5 consecutive rows have a state equals to 1, then here's you could probably do it :

```
SELECT IF(SUM(x.state) = 5, 1, 0) AS is_consecutive 
FROM (
    SELECT state 
    FROM table 
    WHERE Processor = 3
    ORDER BY Status_datetime DESC
    LIMIT 5
) as x
```

If `is_consecutive = 1`, then, yes, there is 5 last consecutive rows with `state = 1`.

**Edit** : As suggested in the comments, you'll have to use `ORDER BY` in your query, to get the last nth rows.

And for more accuracy, since you have a timestamp column, you should use `Status_datetime` to order the rows.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer. I've just tried to run the query and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand the SUM(x.state) = 5, but I don't understand the ', 1, 0' after it.  Can you help me understand it?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Did you know you could you mark this answer as "accepted" (by clicking the green checkbox to the left), so that it gets marked as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this (replace the number in the `HAVING` with the value of `x` you want to check for):

```
SELECT Processor, OpenCount FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 10 Processor, DateTime, Sum(Status) AS OpenCount
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE Processor = 3
   ORDER BY DateTime DESC
) HAVING OpenCount >= 10
```